# Representing number, where digits are cubes

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request

Let $n$ is integer and we want to express it in terms of $10$ as $$n=R^3_k10^k+R^3_{k-1}10^{k-1} \cdots+ R^3_0$$ where $R_i\in \{\pm0,\pm 1,\pm 2,\ldots,\pm9\}$

Example : $37= 1^3\times10+3^3$

Algorithms: Let $$
n = Q_0 \cdot 10+R^3_0,
$$

where $ |R_0| <  10$. Then, we can in turn represent

$$
Q_0 = Q_1 \cdot 10 + R^3_1,
$$

where $ |R_1| <  10 $, and so on, so we can find $R_0, R_1, \dots$ with consecutive division by $10$ and taking remainders.

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        n&=Q_0\cdot 10+R^3_0 \\
        Q_0&= Q_1\cdot 10+R^3_1 \\
        Q_1&= Q_2\cdot 10+R^3_2 \\
       \vdots &=\quad \vdots\\
       Q_{k-2} &= Q_{k-1}\cdot 10+R^3_{k-1}\\
       Q_{k-1} &= 0\cdot f + R^3_{k}
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}

where $R_i\in \{\pm0,\pm 1,\pm 2,\ldots,\pm9\}$

Hence, $n=(R^3_k,R^3_{k-1}, \cdots, R^3_0)_{10}$

Note: For each $Q$ there are $R^3$ and $-R^3_*$ such that $Q\equiv R^3\equiv -R^3_*\pmod{10}$

Example:  \begin{equation*}
        \begin{split}531&=2^3\times 10^2+(-3)^3\times 10+1^3\\
&=(2^3,-3^3,1^3)_{10}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

here representation is not unique. for example

\begin{equation*}
        \begin{split}531
&=(2^3,-3^3,1^3)_{10}\\
&=(1^3,-2^3,-1^3,-4^3,-9^3)_{10}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Define function $D(n)$, calculate minimal degree to represent $n$ in terms of $10$ where coefficients are cube number less than $10^3$ and greater than $-10^3$

so $D(531)=2$ because we can express $531=2\times 10^2+(-3)^3\times 10+1^3$ have degree $2$ and smallest representation.

> Question: Is there any approach to calculate $D(n)$ in fastest way? if yes, what is it?

---

*We can extend this problem to any base and any odd power for coefficient, but I put it in simple way, if you feel to edit above or generalization or grammatical mistake, please go ahead and thanks a lot*.